# Deleting child component state from parent state results in duplicate child DOM among other problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am updating this post with a [link to my full and broken code](http://jsbin.com/mikopixivi/edit?js,console,output). Unfortunately it is breaking in jsbin for a reason I do not understand. But maybe someone will find it useful regardless.

I have a parent component that generates child components. The child components are removed when they animate out of the viewport.

When the child components are removed in the reverse order from their creation, everything works as expected. But when first created is also first removed, the remaining children experience DOM duplication that is not represented in the Parent's state.

As you review the below pseudocode, **I am hoping to learn what in my code is causing the DOM duplication.**

In the below, the deletion occurs by two distinct implementations, one using splice, one using filter. The problem existed just the same when they were both splice.

Heres the code:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     childArray: [],
     nextKey: 0, 
     animInterval: -1,
     ...other state...         
   }
 }
 addChild() {
   let newInterval = this.state.animInterval,
   if (newInterval === -1) {
     newInterval = setInterval(this.updateAnimation.bind(this), this.state.animStep);        
   }
   this.setState({
     childArray: [
       ...childArray,
       {
         id: this.state.nextKey,
         ...other state...
       }
     ],
     nextKey: this.state.nextKey + 1,
     interval: newInterval,
   });
 }

  // this deletes when the child moves off the page,
  // but it seems to cause duplication of child DOM as well 
  // as a halt to css transitions that smooth out the animation steps
  updateAnimation() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      let updated = prevState.bubbleArr.slice()
          remove = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < updated.length; i++) {
        if (!updated[i]) {
          continue;
        }
        updated[i].pos.y += this.state.deltaY;
        if (updated[i].pos.y >= 100+this.state.deltaY) {
          remove.push(i);            
        }
      }
      return { bubbleArr: updated.filter((x,i) => !remove.includes(i))
    };
  });
 }
  render() {
    let styles = {...various styles...}; 
    return (
      <div className="canvas">
        <div
          className="emitter"
          style={styles}
          onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} />

    {this.state.bubbleArr.map(child => (
      <Child
        key={child.id}
        props={bubble}  />
    ))}

  </div>
  ); // above, we are passing the parents handleChildUnmount 
     // to the child to be called on click
  }
} // class

class Child extends React.Component {      
  render() {
    let p = this.props.props, // this is ugly to me, too, but its helping 
        classes = "bubble",   // me not modify the parent's render all the time
        styles = {...various styles to animate...};
    return (
      <div className={classes} style={styles} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
      </div>
    );        
  }
}
```

To recap, my question is:

**Why does removing any child but the last cause that child's DOM to duplicate?**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you add a specific question? It is not totally clear what you are asking.

Comment: @collin-m-barrett Done. Updated.

Comment: Hey @Keira - How about using a more appropriate tool. Put your code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: @Randy nice thanks!

Comment: You are missing comma in updateAnimation after .slice() but that is just copy paste issue probably, because this way you can't run the code.